# Hardware Reserved 4GB (DIMM Slot 1B)

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, bios

So recently my task manager started showing that only 12GB of my 16GB DDR3 RAM in Dual Channel was available stating "Hardware Reserved 4.0 GB"

These are the steps I've currently taken to attempt to rectify the issue.

1. Flashed BIOS
2. Wiped OS and installed to a new drive
3. Set max page file size to recommended (2.5GB)
4. Maximum memory isn't enabled in advanced boot options
5. Replaced the odd stick of RAM *(I had a Kingston HyperX Fury)* with the same model *(now all Corsair Vengeance)* so now all sticks match
6. Resetting CMOS fixed it for a few hours before returning.

I want to avoid the idea that the DIMM slot is faulty due to a CMOS reset fixing it (even if temporarily).

The RAM I'm using is: CMZ12GX3M3A1600C9 (3) and CMZ4GX3M1A1600C9 (1) Both the same model of RAM, but the 3 came in a kit for 12GB whilst the other came as a single kit of 4GB, hence the slight difference in the part numbers.

The motherboard I'm using is 990FXA-UD3 R5.

I'm asking as a seperate question due to the fact I've tried every other suggestion in the other questions and now feel that my situation is unique enough for it's own question.

Comment: If anybody else is having this issue, I did a system recovery and wiped my OS for a fresh reinstall which resolved the issue.

For whatever reason it was not hardware related but OS related. I was unable to find the cause but at the least If found the resolution.